# Dynamic partial naming in node.js using handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

This works fine:

```
<h1 class="uk-heading-line uk-text-center"><span>{{processNameUpper}}</span></h1>
{{> process-BUF-labels}}
```

but now I also want to use a dynamic partial naming like so:

```
<h1 class="uk-heading-line uk-text-center"><span>{{processNameUpper}}</span></h1>
{{> process-{{processNameUpper}}-labels}}
```

But sadly this is not allowed.

Is there any way without a complicated partial expression function?

And I really want to have the labels files in separate files.

Comment: I think you would have to create a helper to compute the name of the partial. It wouldn't need to be a complicated one.

Comment: Yes, I already thought about that. But is there a tutorial for being used in node express? I just found how to use it without express. Thanks.

Comment: The express-handlebars docs have info about using partials: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars